# Verify the signing of manifest and application files

Tags: manifest, clickonce, xbap, mage, assembly-signing

I am exactly using following steps to resign my application manifest and deployment manifest using certificate file.

```
mage -s app-manifest -cf cert_file -pwd password
mage -u deployment-manifest -appm app-manifest
mage -s deployment-manifest -cf certfile -pwd password
```

I want to verify that my manifest files are signed or not and moreover properly signed or not?

I already tried these options:
-Check manifest file after completing the signing process using Mage.exe tool (but the tool still says that the manifest is not signed)
-Using the SignTool to verify (but manifests are not recognized by them, as I suppose SignTool are only to verify application files like .exe/.dll)
-Compare the manifest file before and after signing, where I could see the changes but couldn't figure out if that has been properly signed or not?

So, the question is how could we verify that our manifest file is signed properly? Is there any tool or way out to achieve this?

**Note:** My WPF solution build process will generate the manifests and app files, i.e. MyInstaller.exe.manifest and MyWeb.xbap files.

Regards, 
OM

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's very easy to check for sign. Open this files in any text editor and try to  find  tag. If you have founded it in .application and .manifest file, then your ClickOnce application is currently signed.

Here is 2 examples:

1 - Full signed

[image: Signed]

2 - unsigned project.

[image: Unsigned]

Comment: Ok if that's the only way to find if manifest/app is signed? But still confuses me why when I open the full signed file in Mage tool (MageGUI), then it says file is not signed.

Comment: Your certificate could be expired. Please check certificate expire datetime.

Comment: Sorry to mention it, but the certificate is nto expired but still mage UI tool says the file is not signed. Might be bug in the UI tool itself. 
For now, the other solution of checking the manifest file itself is easy to verify the signed things and I can also check the ManifestCertificateThumbprint to further confirm that it is correctly signed by authentic certificate.

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio Developer Command Prompt, try:

```
mage -verify  MyApp.exe.manifest
Manifest has a valid signature.
```

(however, as far as I see, it only verifies the signature, not that it has been signed with a trusted certificate)